# how to stop keyboard going down and coming up when using "readonly" parameter in text field in flutter

Tags: flutter, textfield

i'm building a 6 digit otp widget using 6 text fields. i want to design in such a way that only focused textfield has to editable and other textfields has be only to show data but shouldn't editable . for this i have used "readOnly" property to true . every thing works fine . but the when the focus is moving from one texfield to other textfield keyboard is going down and comming up . but i want keyboad has be on the screen without moving when i moved from one textifeld to other text field . Can anyone please help me with this? Your assistance would be greatly appreciated.

This is the code that i've written :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class OTPTextField extends StatefulWidget {
  const OTPTextField();

  @override
  OTPTextFieldState createState() => OTPTextFieldState();
}

class OTPTextFieldState extends State<OTPTextField> {
  final List<TextEditingController> _controllers =
      List.generate(6, (_) => TextEditingController());
  final List<FocusNode> _focusNodes = List.generate(6, (_) => FocusNode());

  FocusNode keyBoardFocus = FocusNode();

  final List<bool> _isActive = [true, false, false, false, false, false];
  late int previousIndex;

  void _onTextChanged(int index) {
    if (index != 5) {
      setState(() {
        _isActive[index] = !_isActive[index];
        _isActive[index + 1] = !_isActive[index + 1];
        print("this is from onTextChanged");
        print(_isActive);
      });
      FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_focusNodes[index + 1]);
    }
  }

  void onTextFieldTap() {
    final index = _isActive.indexOf(true);
    print("......" + index.toString() + ">>>>>>>");
    FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_focusNodes[index]);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: RawKeyboardListener(
        focusNode: keyBoardFocus,
        onKey: (keyEvent) {
          if (keyEvent.logicalKey == LogicalKeyboardKey.backspace &&
              keyEvent.runtimeType.toString() == "RawKeyDownEvent") {
            final index = _isActive.indexOf(true);
            print("this is triggered on keyboard listener on $index");
            if (index > 0) {
              setState(() {
                _isActive[index] = !_isActive[index];
                _isActive[index - 1] = !_isActive[index - 1];
                print(_isActive);
                FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_focusNodes[index - 1]);
                _controllers[index - 1].text = "";
              });
            }
          }
        },
        child: Center(
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: List.generate(6, (index) {
              return SizedBox(
                width: 35,
                height: 600,
                child: GestureDetector(
                  // behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
                  onTap: () {
                    print("tap............tap,,,,,,,,,,");
                  },
                  child: TextField(
                    maxLength: 1,
                    autofocus: index == 0,
                    onTap: (() {
                      print("tap ..... tap.....");
                      onTextFieldTap();
                    }),
                    readOnly: !_isActive[index],
                    cursorColor: Colors.black,
                    cursorWidth: 2,
                    cursorRadius: const Radius.circular(5),
                    controller: _controllers[index],
                    focusNode: _focusNodes[index],
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                      ),
                    ),
                    inputFormatters: [FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly],
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                    textInputAction: index == 5
                        ? TextInputAction.done
                        : TextInputAction.next,
                    onChanged: (value) => _onTextChanged(index),
                  ),
                ),
              );
            }),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```